# displaying dates on x axis with Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axis

I’m building a bar chart with highcharts.js. The x-axis is an array of dates, while the y-axis is an array of numbers from 0-100. I want to display the dates on the X axis but only show ticks when there is a new date. If you look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/6621/) you can see the current plot and how the dates look bad. Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/) and how it displays the dates in an elegant way. Essentially I want to only show a few ticks on the x-axis while plotting many data points.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: dates ,
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: ticks

        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add minTickInterval to your xAxis settings:

```
xAxis: {
            categories: dates ,
            crosshair: true,
            minTickInterval: 24
        }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @Orilux